# Does possessing an enemy count towards chaos?

Tags: dishonored

I want to get the "low chaos" ending in my Dishonered playthrough. I know that killing enemies will count towards more chaos. Does possessing an enemy also count towards the chaos score?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Sumurai8 saw it. As I'm not sure, I'll comment: I think that possessing causes chaos.

Comment: @ardaozkal Perfectly clear to me. Have you actually played Dishonored?

Comment: @Studoku It wasn't clear before edit. I'm stuck in middle of somewhere. I have low hp and it is full of guards. Will finish if I get through there.

Answer (score 2):

No, possessing guards does not directly increase chaos, as long as the guard survives. If the guard is killed because of possessing him, e.g. falling off a ledge after the possession ends, that counts as a kill.

Chaos is caused by kills and certain quest/side-quest objectives in a dangerous and destructive way.